# Cannot remove Object3D objects from the scene

Tags: three.js, augmented-reality

I'm working on an augmented reality app.

I'm developing the app on top of this open source available. (https://github.com/jeromeetienne/threex.webar/blob/master/examples/basic.html)

In the above open source, when any number of markers are shown to the camera, only one image is augmented on top of it irrespective of the markers. In my scenario, I want to make one marker to be specific to one image ie., every time a marker is shown, the image specific to that marker should be augmented.

I have the following code written to meet the scenario requirement.

```
   var markerObjects = [];
   var images = ['images/cadbury.png','images/kitkat.png','images/gems.png']
   for ( i=265,j=0;i<268,j<images.length;i++,j++ ) {
    markerObjects.push({id:i,image:images[j],Object3D: new     THREE.Object3D()})
  }

   markerObjects.forEach(function(objects) {
    objects.Object3D.visible = false ;
  })

    detectMarkersStats.begin();
    var markers = jsArucoMarker.detectMarkers(domElement)
    detectMarkersStats.end();

    markers.forEach(function(marker) {
        markerObjects.forEach(function(markerObject) {
            if( marker.id == markerObject.id ) {
                var material = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({
                map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( markerObject.image ),
                });
                var object3d = new THREE.Sprite(material);
                object3d.scale.set( 2, 2, 1 );
                markerObject.Object3D.add(object3d);
                jsArucoMarker.markerToObject3D(marker, markerObject.Object3D)
                scene.add( markerObject.Object3D );
                markerObject.Object3D.visible = true;
            } 
        });
    });
```

The problem I'm facing is whenever I show a marker to camera, the image is augmented but the image remains on the scene when the marker is taken away from the camera. If multiple markers are shown, all the images are augmented but all of them remains on the scene. I want to remove those images from the scene once the markers are taken off from the camera.

Can you guys please help me to arrive at a solution?

Comment: from your code is quite obvious that the augmentation media is not removed from the scene. You add it (scene.add( markerObject.Object3D );) but you never remove it. There must be a way to verify when your marker is removed from the camera view and then remove the corresponding object (I assume something like scene.remove(...).